# mysql changing where clause if join exists

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

What I want to do is join the same table and see if the field "reference_id" has a value, if it does then it should use that value to get the actual row with data and use that data for the rest of the query - where and sort clauses, otherwise use the original entries data.

Table "entries" fields:

```
id, text, type, reference_id, num_count
```

Example data:

```
[1, "", 0, 2, 0],
[2, "some text", 2, 0, 50],
[3, "more text", 2, 0, 60],
```

Should return:

```
row 0: "more text"
row 1: "some text"
```

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT entries.text
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN entries as e2
     ON entries.reference_id = e2.id 
WHERE type = $type
ORDER BY num_count DESC
```

So the last two clauses should change from `entries.type` and `entries.num_count` to `e2.type` and `e2.num_count` if reference_id has something. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please post more details, according to your comment on @Santosh Patel, 'because the original query has way too many where clauses to add "or"s to them'. So please post more details so we can be of better assistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you just want to use the left joined table values if they exist, otherwise the main tables values.

I so something like this:-

```
SELECT COALESCE(e2.text, entries.text)
FROM entries
LEFT OUTER JOIN entries as e2
ON entries.reference_id = e2.id 
WHERE type = $type
ORDER BY COALESCE(e2.num_count, entries.num_count) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the COALESCE() worked, never heard of it before now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please write with alias in where clause

```
    SELECT entries.text
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN entries as e2
     ON entries.reference_id = e2.id 
WHERE entries.type = $type
ORDER BY entries.num_count DESC
```

Comment: I'm looking to see if there is a way to do it without "or", because the original query has way too many where clauses to add "or"s to them.

Comment: or means first or second as you want. If you want to apply condition on e2 then write second line . And if you want to apply condition on entries then write first line. not both line with or.